# how to post Image multipart/form-data from pl/sql to a web service?

Tags: plsql, multipartform-data

I want to send Image from plsql code to my web service.
I am using APEX 21.1 on oracle database 18c xe Apache Tomcat listener.
In my web service i need to send only path of image in multipart/form-data.

following code are using to send file but dont know how to add parameter.

```
    DECLARE
  p_url          VARCHAR2(255) := 'http://192.168.0.120:8000/api/v1/recognition/faces';
  utl_req        utl_http.req;
  utl_resp       utl_http.resp;
  req_length     BINARY_INTEGER;
  response_body  VARCHAR2(32767);
  p_request_body clob;
  l_newline      VARCHAR2(50) := chr(13) || chr(10);
  lco_boundary CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := '----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW';
  buffer raw(32767);
  amount number(15) := 32767;
  offset number(15) := 21;

  l_attachment blob;
  l_file_name  VARCHAR2(255);
  l_mime_type  VARCHAR2(255);
  
  l_response_header_name varchar2(256);
  l_response_header_value varchar2(1024);
  l_response_body varchar2(32767);

  lang_context integer;
  warning      varchar2(1000);
  blb          blob;

  tmp_blob blob default EMPTY_BLOB();

  dest_offset integer := 1;
  src_offset  integer := 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT IMAGE, FILENAME, MIMETYPE
        INTO l_attachment, l_file_name, l_mime_type
        FROM TEST_TABLE
        WHERE ID_ID = 21;

  p_request_body := l_newline || '--' || lco_boundary || l_newline ||
                    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' ||
                    l_file_name || '"' || l_newline || 'Content-Type: ' ||
                    l_mime_type || l_newline ||
                    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked' || l_newline ||
                    l_newline ||
                    apex_web_service.blob2clobbase64(l_attachment) ||
                    l_newline || '--' || lco_boundary || '--';
  dbms_output.put_line(p_request_body);

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(blb, FALSE);
  dest_offset  := 1;
  src_offset   := 1;
  lang_context := 0;
  dbms_lob.converttoblob(blb,
                         p_request_body,
                         dbms_lob.getlength(p_request_body),
                         dest_offset,
                         src_offset,
                         0,
                         lang_context,
                         warning);
  dbms_lob.append(blb, l_attachment);
  req_length := dbms_lob.getlength(blb);

  utl_req := utl_http.begin_request(url          => p_url,
                                    method       => 'POST',
                                    http_version => 'HTTP/1.1');                                
  utl_http.set_header(utl_req, 'content-type', 'multipart/form-data');                            
  utl_http.set_header(utl_req, 'x-api-key', 'ce83481a-701f-xxxx-a3ec-exxxxxb5665e');
  utl_http.set_header(utl_req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
  utl_http.set_header(utl_req,
                      'Content-Type',
                      'multipart/form-data; boundary="' || lco_boundary || '"');
  dbms_output.put_line(req_length);

  IF req_length <= 32767 THEN
    utl_http.set_header(utl_req, 'Content-Length', req_length);
    utl_http.write_raw(utl_req, blb);
  ELSIF req_length > 32767 THEN
    utl_http.set_header(utl_req, 'Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    WHILE (offset < req_length) LOOP
      dbms_lob.read(blb, amount, offset, buffer);
      utl_http.write_raw(utl_req, buffer);
      offset := offset + amount;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;

  utl_resp := utl_http.get_response(utl_req);
  
  dbms_output.put_line('Response> Status Code: ' || utl_resp.status_code);
  
  for i in 1 .. utl_http.get_header_count(utl_resp) loop
    utl_http.get_header(utl_resp, i, l_response_header_name, l_response_header_value);
    dbms_output.put_line('Response> ' || l_response_header_name || ': ' || l_response_header_value);
  end loop;

  utl_http.read_text(utl_resp, l_response_body, 32767);
  
  --utl_http.read_raw(utl_resp, response_body, 32767);
  
  dbms_output.put_line('Response body>');
  dbms_output.put_line(l_response_body);
  
  utl_http.end_response(utl_resp);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_HTTP.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS THEN
    utl_http.END_RESPONSE(utl_resp);
  
END;
```

in postman it is working fine

```
POST /api/v1/recognition/faces?subject=56543 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.120:8000
content-type: multipart/form-data
x-api-key: ce83481a-701f-xxxx-a3ec-exxxxxb5665e
Content-Length: 188
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/C:/facerec/ASASAS.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

guide me to solve my problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually came across this issue a bit of time ago. I didn't solve it myself, instead I used a package written by Rafael Uchoa.

Here's the link to the github: https://github.com/rafaeluchoa/utl_http_multipart

As to your issue. Turn the image into a BLOB, then use the procedure:

```
utl_http_multipart.add_file(...)
-- https://github.com/rafaeluchoa/utl_http_multipart
```